# MVC 5 tooling support in class library project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

We have a large `WebForms` website (not web project) and we are adding several MVC pages. Initially we placed `Controllers` and `ViewModels`/`InputModels` in the `App_Code` folder. After working with the setup for a few days, we decided that this would be hard to maintain and reuse in the future, so we decided to move the `Controllers` and `Models` in to thier own class library.

I was wondering if it is possible to have the MVC tooling support (like Right-Click-> Add... -> Controller... and such) in a class library project.

I did a little searching and found several solutions talking about project type `GUID`s and such, but I see that for MVC >5 there is no special project type any more.

What is the alternative (if one even exists) for getting the tooling support in a class library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to create the class library as an MVC project (even though it will never be deployed standalone) in order to have the tooling support.

Edit: There are some workarounds such as Razor intellisense from a fake web.config etc, but I've found all of these lacking when compared to full support.

Comment: But how does the VS IDE "mark" a project as an MVC web project? Is it just the fact that it is a web project? Why couldn't I then just edit the existing class library project file to the same effect?

Comment: You could, it has to do with the project type guid in the .proj file, but I've found it easier just to create a new project through the IDE and copy the files across. (because you also need a web.config etc)

Comment: I unloaded the project, added project type GUIDs as needed, reloaded the project and now I have full tooling support. Thank you.